# "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" exception after rotate device

Tags: android, dialogfragment, onsaveinstancestate

I have a ViewHolder and in bindView() method set a **OnLongClickListener**.

When I rotate device and long click on list item **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState** exception occurs.

I've already override show() method and tested **commitAllowingStateLoss** but still get exception.

Anyone can help me?

```
public void bindView(final FragmentActivity activity) {

    ...

    itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            FingerprintDialogFragment fingerprintDialogFragment = FingerprintDialogFragment.getInstance(DecreeItemViewHolder.this);
            fingerprintDialogFragment.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), FINGERPRINT_DIALOG_TAG);

            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of passing Activity to Adapter to Viewholder, try passing a LongClickListener

Comment: Thank you, your solution get me an idea... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by a delegation...

1. Add **checkFingerprintAuthentication()** method in **Caller Class**:

   ```
   void checkFingerprintAuthentication() {
       FingerprintDialogFragment fingerprintDialogFragment = FingerprintDialogFragment.getInstance(this);
       fingerprintDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), FINGERPRINT_DIALOG_TAG);
   }
   ```
2. Send Caller Class as a parameter to **View Holder** and call **checkFingerprintAuthentication()**:

   ```
   public void bindView(final DecreeCartableController cartableController) {
       ...

       itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
               cartableController.checkFingerprintAuthentication();
               return true;
          }
      });
   }
   ```

problem solved! :)